# Usablity vs security malicious file upload

Tags: web-application, file-upload, threat-mitigation

We were designing a web application which has the functionality similar to vulnerability management, our web application functionality can be briefed as follows:

- There is a panel where one can launch a program for listing vulnerabilities
- Bob launches his program through our web application
- Alice reports the vulnerability with malicious file
- Bob receives report with malicious file and gets a warning stating that **download might have relative consequences**
- Bob downloads the malicious file and fall as victim for Alice

Now as per functionality/usability my developer argues that.

- We can allow malicious file upload to the application as its core feature of the application (Alice will upload vulnerable file as proof of concept)
- We were showing warning message, its enough to prevent users from downloading malicious file, since all users would be tech-savy

Now my argument was as follows:

- Attacker can user this platform to social engineer the response team (here Bob would get infected)
- As a responsible vendor, the clients will trust us and download the file
- Also I referred [unrestricted file upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)

So considering above situation what would be the best bet to prevent my clients from being fallen as victim for attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disallow file uploads, researchers will host their proof-of-concepts elsewhere and provide you with a link to the remote resource, leaving you with essentially the same problem.

*The common practice varies.* The popular platform [HackerOne](https://hackerone.com/) (which provides pretty much the service you described) **allows file uploads**, but includes an appropriate warning before offering the download. Google's bug bounty program, on the other hand, **does not allow uploads** on their [bug report form](https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new).

Either way, your **response team** should work in a *sandboxed environment* and *open files only if necessary*. I disagree that uploads are "*a core feature"*, as many vulnerabilities can be explained without attachments but via plain text and inline code snippets - although your customers might think otherwise.

*Hosting the attachments securely* is a topic to itself, but most importantly, you should store all user uploads on a server separate from your web application.